How can I create a responsive grid layout with CSS Grid that maintains equal column heights?
I'm trying to create a responsive grid layout using CSS Grid where all columns maintain equal heights, regardless of their content. The goal is to have a layout where each column has the same height, and the grid adapts to different screen sizes.
Currently, the columns have different heights based on their content. How can I ensure that all columns in the grid have equal height, while still being responsive to different screen sizes?
Any suggestions or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!


.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2 with more content</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4 with even more content that makes it taller</div>
</div>




You can use
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; 



.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; /* all rows are the same height */
}

.item {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: stretch; /* Ensure content stretches to fill the item */
}
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2 with more content</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4 with even more content that makes it taller</div>
</div>



